# Tracing timestamp of XML request/responses with JAX-WS

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic, jax-ws

We have created a JAX-WS webservice, this service is being invoked by multiple clients. Some clients have configured timeout for API response. Even after sending success response, some client are stating that request is being timed out.

**So is there any way to track, at what time a particular request hits the server and what time server responded back** ?

I've enable http traces in weblogic server by using below properties

> -Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true
>   -Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true

**And request and response are appearing like below, where timestamp is missing**

```
---[HTTP request - ]---
Accept: text/xml, multipart/related
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: ""

---[HTTP response  200]---
null: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 521
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
```

**Weblogic Version is - 12.2.1**

Comment: What is your weblogic server version ?

At first you can start with weblogic server's http log files (access logs) where you will find client's requests. Configure http log file in extended mode and add the field time-taken to see how long it takes to WebLogic server to handle soap requests.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin Weblogic version is 12.2.1.
Any idea or link about how to configure log file in extended mode ?

Comment: Access log documentation is available here : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24432/web_server.htm#CNFGD204